# Format to print to one decimal point for temperature

Tags: java, formatting, decimal

I am very new to Java and I have to write a program that takes from -40 to 120 Fahrenheit and convert it to Celsius and then display them in two columns with increments of 5 and accurate to one decimal place. I have most of the code finished and I have the right output for the Fahrenheit but I can't figure out how to get the Celsius to print accurate to one decimal place. Anything would be helpful!

```
package 3;

public class prog2 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Fahrenheit to Celsius converter from -40F below to 120F");
          for(double temp = -40.0; temp <= 120; temp += 5) 
          {
             System.out.printf("%10.1f", temp);
             double sum = (temp -32) * (5.0/9.0);  
             System.out.printf("%5d",(int) sum );
             System.out.println();          
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%10.1f", temp);` ... seems to moving in the right direction

Comment: Maybe you should **print a space** between the 2 values. You can also combine all 3 print statements into one: `System.out.printf("%10.1f %5d%n", temp, (int) ((temp - 32) * 5 / 9));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the printing of sum to this:

`System.out.printf(" %10.1f", sum );`

Formatting is same as for the first column and don't cast the calculated value to int.

Comment: That is literally what I just did before reading your comment...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use DecimalFormat class by sending in the constructor a formating string. In your exemple '#' means one digits and the '.' means decimal point.
check this link for more https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

you can do something like that :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Fahrenheit to Celsius converter from -40F below to 120F");
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
    for (double temp = -40.0; temp <= 120; temp += 5) {
        System.out.printf("%sC°", df.format(temp));
        double sum = (temp - 32) * (5.0 / 9.0);
        System.out.printf("= %sF°", df.format(sum));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```